# Toggle minor modes in all current and future buffers derived from specific major mode

Tags: hooks, minor-mode, hl-line-mode

I am new to elisp. That's why I'd be glad if some of you could help me out.

**What I want to achieve**

I want to enable `hl-line-mode` and `display-line-number-mode` in all current and future buffers derived from `prog-mode`, `text-mode`, `conf-mode` and `dired-mode`. I also want to be able to toggle this functionality. By default I want this to be turned off. I just want to enable this from time to time.

I'll outline the high level way I thought about achieving this.

**Adding functionality**

- Add mode hooks to enable functionality in future buffers. **(1)**
- Apply buffer-local minor mode functions to all buffers derived from specific modes. **(2)**

**Removing functionality**

- Remove mode hooks such that future buffers don't have it. **(3)**
- Apply buffer-local minor mode functions to all buffers derived from specfic modes to toggle/disable functionality activated in step 2 above. This step might the same as step 2 above because `hl-line-mode` and `display-line-number-mode` provide toggling. **(4)**

I know how to add and remove hooks but I don't know how implement steps 2 and 4. Especially checking whether buffers are in a mode derived from a specific major mode or not.

I'd be really happy to receive some help on how to go about it.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Just to clarify what I actually want, if I wasn't precise enough:**

1. Line numbers and line highlighting should be disabled when I launch emacs.
2. When the need arises, I want to call a function interactively that immediately turns on `display-line-numbers-mode` and `hl-line-mode` in all current buffers that match the requirements specified in my original post. With all current buffers I mean all buffers selectable via `switch-to-buffer`. Furthermore this function should also modify `prog-mode-hook`, `text-mode-hook` and so on, such that all buffers matching the requirements that I open in the future have `display-line-numbers-mode` and `hl-line-mode` enabled.
3. When I don't need line numbers and line highlighting anymore I want to call a different interactive function such that `display-line-numbers-mode` and `hl-line-mode` get turned off immediately in all current buffers that match the requirements. Furthermore this function should also remove previously added functions from `prog-mode-hook`, `text-mode-hook` and so on, such that all buffers matching the requirements that I open in the future **do not** have `display-line-numbers-mode` and `hl-line-mode` enabled.

This is just my naive way of thinking about the problem. More knowledgeable people might be able to implement equivalent functionality in a better, more idiomatic way.

**ANOTHER EDIT: I got it working. It's ugly though:**

I got it working exactly how I want it to work.
It's very ugly and the code can probably be shortened. Especially the parts adding/removing hooks.
Any suggestions on how to do so?

```
(defun my/activate ()
  (interactive)
  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)
  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
  (add-hook 'conf-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)
  (add-hook 'conf-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
  (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)
  (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
  (dolist ($buf (buffer-list))
    (with-current-buffer $buf
      (when (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode 'prog-mode 'conf-mode 'text-mode)
        (lambda)
        (hl-line-mode)
        (display-line-numbers-mode)))))
```

```
(defun my/deactivate ()
  (interactive)
  (remove-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)
  (remove-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
  (remove-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)
  (remove-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
  (remove-hook 'conf-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)
  (remove-hook 'conf-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
  (remove-hook 'text-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)
  (remove-hook 'text-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
  (dolist ($buf (buffer-list))
    (with-current-buffer $buf
      (when (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode 'prog-mode 'conf-mode 'text-mode)
        (lambda)
        (hl-line-mode -1)
        (display-line-numbers-mode -1)))))
```

Comment: You can define a variable with the list of all the modes as value and then loop over that to add/remove hooks, as well as use it when checking for derived modes. Other than that, I think your solution is fine.

Comment: What's with the `(lambda)` in both functions? That doesn't do anything: just delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "globalized" minor mode, which is the pairing of a buffer local minor mode with a global mode which *controls* the state of that buffer-local minor mode en-masse in selected buffers (including any future buffers matching the criteria). Globalized modes act during `after-change-major-mode-hook`, which is later than the major mode's own hook.

```el
(define-globalized-minor-mode global-my-mode my-mode my-mode
  :init-value nil
  :predicate '(prog-mode text-mode conf-mode dired-mode))

(define-minor-mode my-mode
  "Enable line numbering and highlighting."
  :init-value nil
  :global nil
  (let ((state (if my-mode 1 0)))
    (hl-line-mode state)
    (display-line-numbers-mode state)))
```

Then just use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `global-my-mode` to toggle it.

If you're using Emacs 27 or earlier you can't use `:predicate` and instead you'll need to specify a separate TURN-ON function in the globalized mode definition:

```el
(defun my-mode-turn-on ()
  "Maybe turn on `my-mode'."
  (when (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode 'text-mode 'conf-mode 'dired-mode)
    (my-mode 1)))
```

Comment: You could alternatively use this approach to create *two* custom global modes, *directly* controlling `hl-line-mode` and `display-line-numbers-mode` respectively (rather than defining your own buffer-local mode).  It seems simpler to me to combine all of the desired functionality into a single mode, however.  If you prefer that alternative though, make sure you still use sane non-conflicting naming (bearing in mind that both of the minor modes being controlled *already* have associated global modes by default).

Answer (score 0):

Here comes [derived-mode-p](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Derived-Modes.html) function to your rescue.

```el
(defun my-unset-minor-modes-hook ()
  (when (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode 'text-mode 'conf-mode 'dired-mode)
    (hl-line-mode -1)
    (display-line-number-mode -1)))
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'my-unset-minor-modes-hook)
```

You can alternatively consider `change-major-mode-hook` in the place of `after-change-major-mode-hook` to add your hook to.
[Edit] As phils noted in comments, this may do the work but in spirit, `change-major-mode-hook` is meant to do cleanup operations by the exiting mode & `after-change-major-mode-hook` is the more suited candidate to do mode initialising operations. So, it is wise to add the hook to `after-change-major-mode-hook`.

Comment: @Saravana: Good answer, but I'm confused by the `change-major-mode-hook` mention -- that one runs while the *previous* mode is still active.  It's usually used to enable a major mode to clean up after itself just before some other mode takes its place.  You certainly couldn't use it in place of `after-change-major-mode-hook`.

Comment: Gosh! the names din't tell the difference, at least to me. thanks for clarifying, phils.

Comment: You're welcome.  You might find https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380/324105 to be a worthwhile read.